# How to get a java client to connect to a JBoss 7 server using a custom login module

Tags: java, security, ejb, jboss7.x

I've been going through the Picketbox example:
https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossAS7SecurityCustomLoginModules

and I could get the entire example to work and login via the war file (using the web browser). But my problem is that the example does not explain how to login with a simple java app.

The war file (form-auth.war) has a jboss-web.xml file that specifies the security-domain:
form-auth
and this seems to be critical, if it is, where do I specify this from the java app?

If the code in the war file can login via the browser, then it must be possible to get a java client app to do the same. I probably need to debug/hunt down how the war file gets executed to determine how it successfully logs into JBoss.